# Javascript Math returning NaN

Tags: javascript, html

My math all seems to be correct, but I'm returning a NaN.

The Javascript:

```
// This section calculates how much the user will have to spend until the average age of life expectancy.
function updatespending() {
  var age = parseFloat(document.forms[0].CurrentAge.value);
  var value = parseFloat(document.forms[0].NetWorth.value);
  if(document.forms[0].sex.value == "male")
     {var yearsleft = Math.round (76 - age);}
  else if(document.forms[0].sex.value == "female") 
     {var yearsleft = 81 - age;}
  document.forms[0].AnnualSpending.value = Math.round (value / years left);
```

The HTML code:

```
<table width="433" border="1" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td class="liquidate">How much will you have to live off of if you liquidate all of your assets?</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="381" height="68"><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
      <tr>
        <td align="right">Sex:</td>
        <td>
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right">Current Age:</td>
        <td><input type="text" onchange="updatespending()" onkeyup="numericOnly(this)" maxlength="2" size="3" value="0" name="CurrentAge" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right" >Annual Spending Available:</td>
        <td>$<input name="AnnualSpending" disabled="disabled" readonly /></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is, of course, all encompassed in a form. If I remove the == and put a = , it will return whatever the first if statement says. Anything else returns a NaN. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's not how you get the value of radio buttons.

Comment: try to check what is your variable AGE value, put a debugger or console log variable that  use to calculate

Comment: where is your elment named `NetWorth`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thorbjørn Kappel Hanser has one part of your problem, the other is:

```
document.forms[0].sex.value == "male"
```

note that *sex* is a radio group, so `document.forms[0].sex` returns a NodeList that doesn't have a *value* property. You need to determine which radio button is checked, then get its value, e.g.

```
function getRadioGroupValue(group) {
  for (var i=0, iLen=group.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if (group[i].checked) {
      return group[i].value;
    }
  }
}
```

and then:

```
var sex = getRadioGroupValue(document.forms[0].sex);
if (sex == 'male') { 
  ...
}
```

Comment: There are only two possible values (`male` and `female`), so it might be more appropriate to just check whether the first node, `male`, is checked. Something like `var sex = document.forms[0].sex[0].checked ? "male" : "female";` This assumes a selection has been made. To check for selections, replace `"female"` with `document.forms[0].sex[1].checked? "female" : null`.

Comment: @Luxelin—what if neither are checked? While it's good practice to have one checked by default, the OP (and lots of others on the web) hasn't done that.

Comment: I addressed that. You would replace `"female"` in the first part so that you have `var sex = document.forms[0].sex[0].checked ? "male" : document.forms[0].sex[1].checked ? "female" : null;`. This would probably be more readable as an if/else block.

Comment: Come to find out that part of the problem was that I was using double "quotes" vice single 'quotes' using this solution and changing the quotes is what fixed it.  I also added an on change command that if they select one or the other, that it would also change the values.

Answer (score 2):

On your last line you have:

```
document.forms[0].AnnualSpending.value = Math.round (value / years left);
```

Shouldn't that be:

```
document.forms[0].AnnualSpending.value = Math.round (value / yearsleft);
```

Note the yearsLeft variable.

Comment: For whatever reason, that was my computer that did that. I have no space in the yearsleft var.

Answer (score 0):

NaN means NaN meaning you're trying to add either letters or symbols to numbers which isn't possible.